# When I draw on X11 windows can I immediately see it?

Tags: linux, x11, xlib

I am porting a Windows app and some concepts are unclear. For example when I output some text on the window I use the following pseudo code:

```
(create a window)
...
hdc=GetDC(the window)
TexOut("Hello world")
ReleaceDC(my hdc etc)
...
while (1)
   some code to handle stuff
```

At the point of ReleaseDC my text is shown on the screen.
When using  X11/Xlib on linux I dont get anything until an event loop is processed. For example:

```
(create a window)
...
TexOut("Hello world")
...
while (1)
   some code to handle stuff
   if (expose etc)
      XDrawStrin("Hi there")
..,
```

In above example only "Hi there" is shown.
How do I get "Hello world" to show also?

Comment: `XFlush` should be the answer.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in comment, `XFlush` is the proper answer.  If you want to be certain that the screen updates have been made before proceeding to some more interesting task, `XSync` may be an improvement.

Further reading:

- [**`XFlush`**, **`XSync`**, **`XEventsQueued`**, **`XPending`** - handle output buffer or event queue](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/XSync.3.html)
- [XSync, XFlush or XSynchronize for speeding up drawing requests??](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.windows.x/nssesk1zyUY)